# How can I bypass the rest of the 'then's in a promise chain, like a traditional 'return' statement?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I am leaving behind my synchronous, multi-threaded Java programming world and embracing the single-threaded, asynchronous, promise-based world of ES6 JavaScript. I have had to catch on to this concept of mapping functions written in a synchronous style to async promise-based functions. I am currently using a mix of ES6 native Promises and bluebird promises.

I'll start with an example to set the stage for my question (synchronous examples in Java, async examples in ES6):

**Synchronous Function**

```
private Object doSomething(Object var1, Object var2) {
    Object var3 = blockingFunction(var1);
    Object var4 = anotherBlockingFunction(var2, var3);
    return var4;
}
```

**Asynchronous Promise-based equivlanet**

```
function doSomething(var1, var2) {
    return asyncFunction(var1)
    .then(var3 => {
        return anotherAsyncFunction(var2, var3);
    })
    .then(var4 => {
        return var4;
    });
}
```

*Now here's my question*: Is there a clean (i.e. built-in, already thought of) way to simulate the synchronous `return` idea to bypass the rest of the return chain?

To explain, here are two more synchronous and asynchronous examples:

**Synchronous Function**

```
private Object doSomething(Object var1, Object var2) {
    Object var3 = blockingFunction(var1);
    Object var4 = anotherBlockingFunction(var2, var3);
    if (!var4.isValid()) {
        return var3;
    }
    // If var4.isValid() equates to false, we bypass the following statements
    // and return the value of var3 as the final value
    Object var5 = var4.validateObject();
    var5.setSomething(var1);
    return var5;
}
```

(My guess at an) **Asynchronous Promise-based equivalent**

```
function doSomething(var1, var2) {
    // Predefine variables within this block so they persist between 'then's
    let var3;
    let var4;
    let var5;
    let bypassCondition;
    return asyncFunction(var1)
    .then(result => {
        var3 = result;
        return anotherAsyncFunction(var2, var3);
    })
    .then(result => {
        var4 = result;
        bypassCondition = !var4.valid;
        if(bypassCondition) {
            return var3;
        }
    })
    .endChain(bypassCondition)
    // If the bypassCondition is true, the entire chain would return the value
    // of the previous then's return;
    // Otherwise, if false, the chain continues
    .then(() => {
        return var4.validateObject();
    })
    .then(result => {
        var5 = result;
        var5.something = var1;
        return var5;
    });
}
```

Does something like this already exist?

I am aware of these alternatives, so perhaps I can told whether or not either is actually the right way to do it:

- Throw an exception in the middle of the chain and catch it at the end, so that other statements are bypassed
- Wrap each subsequent `then`'s function in an `if (!bypassCondition)` block so that they won't all be executed

Comment: Put all the subsequent `then`s in the "`else` block". There is no early exiting from promise chains, that only works with functions. You could use an `async function`, however.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for that link. I had come across your answer to the question you linked before, but I didn't understand that it was a solution to my question until you linked it to this specific question. Though I'd agree this is a duplicate, for closure's sake, I'd like to post an answer so that it is clear how to accomplish what I am trying to do. Is that possible?

Comment: Glad to have helped by putting the link :-) There are in fact [many more pretty similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=break+chain+[promise]). I think we normally don't allow answers to duplicate questions, but I've reopened so that you can [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) the question. Please just put some sentence like "This answer over here [link] has helped me" at the top and leave me an upvote :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29500221/1733377) is where I was able to obtain my answer to this question.

As Bergi pointed out, what I am doing here is branching. All I need to do is put the continuing branch *inside* the else block, like so:

```
function doSomething(var1, var2) {
    // Predefine variables within this block so they persist between 'then's
    let var3;
    let var4;
    let var5;
    return asyncFunction(var1)
    .then(result => {
        var3 = result;
        return anotherAsyncFunction(var2, var3);
    })
    .then(result => {
        var4 = result;
        if(!var4.valid) {
            return var3;
        }
        else {
            return Promise.resolve()
            .then(() => {
                return var4.validateObject();
             })
             .then(result => {
                var5 = result;
                var5.something = var1;
                return var5;
             });
        })
    }
}
```

Fundamentally, you *cannot* stop a promise chain. Even though it looks like I should be able to, remember that other functions will append `.then(...)` to the output of your function. The code has no distinction as to if the `then` statements appear within one function or outside of it, so what I was proposing, `.endchain(...)`, would have to end all other users of the promise chain *outside* of the function, making the chain ultimately un-useable.

Using this branching method, the traditional `return` behavior I was after is accomplished, because the last `then` in a chain before the end of the function is where the chain will pick up when its return value is used outside of the function — in this case, either after `return var3;` if `var4.valid` is `false`, or after `return var5;` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You're talking about conditional flow in promise-chains, of which early return is a useful flavor.

Yes this is possible, by branching your chain conditionally. Keep an eye on the parenthesis:

```
function doSomething(var1, var2) {
  return asyncFunction(var1)
  .then(var3 => anotherAsyncFunction(var2, var3))
  .then(var4 => (!var4.isValid())? var3 : var4.validateObject()
    .then(var5 => (var5.something = var1, var5)));
}
```

Note the indentation on the last line, where the `.then` is off of `var4.validateObject()`.

This maps quite well to ES7 (where we can do an early bail to boot):

```
async function doSomething(var1, var2) {
  let var3 = await asyncFunction(var1);
  let var4 = await anotherAsyncFunction(var2, var3);
  if (!var4.isValid()) {
    return var3;
  }
  let var5 = await var4.validateObject();
  var5.something = var1;
  return var5;
}
```

(You didn't specify whether `validateObject` was async or not, so I went with async).

Comment: After Bergi's suggestion to check out async functions, I now see that they ultimately accomplish what I am trying to do. Promises may be _so much_ better than plain old callbacks, but async functions appear to be _so much_ better than promises because I don't have to completely leave the sequential paradigm. They can't receive support soon enough!

Comment: @MichaelPlautz note that async functions are mere syntactic sugar on top of promises, so they go hand-in-hand (e.g. `asyncFunction` above really returns a promise). For instance, `Promise.all` etc. can still be used in async functions to run things in parallel, even in the sequential realm.