# how could I abort JavaScript Promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, chaining

I am working On `NodeJS` Project  , I used Promise In my code 
to chain some methods , I needed to abort in one of the 'thens' chain

```
findEmployeeByCW('11111', "18-09-2016").
then(function () {
    return findEmployeeByCWE('111111', "18-09-2016", '111111')
}, function () {
    console.log('createEmployeeLoginBy')
    createEmployeeLoginBy('111111', "18-09-2016", '111111').
    then(function (log) {
        SaveEmployeeLogToDb(log)
        // ***************
        // ^_^ I need to exit here ....
    })
})
.then(function (log) {
    return updateLoginTimeTo(log, '08-8668', '230993334')
}, function () {
    return createNewEmployeeLog('224314', "18-09-2016",
        '230993334', '08-99')
})
.then(SaveEmployeeLogToDb).then(DisplayLog).catch(function (e) {
    console.log(e);
})
```

Comment: You can store a reference to your promise and then call `reject` on that after `SaveEmployeeLogToDB`

Comment: you can just throw an error and the promise will get rejected

Comment: @mortezaT unfortunately  I used that , but it executed the next then's reject

Comment: @MohammadAbdullah Then maybe Johannes's be a better way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cancel an EMCAScript6 (vanilla JavaScript) promise chain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478751/how-to-cancel-an-emcascript6-vanilla-javascript-promise-chain)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly break out of a promise chain?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29499582/1048572)

Comment: @MohammadAbdullah What exactly do you mean by "exit"? Why not just move all the things that you don't want to do in case of an error into the `success` callback?

Comment: @Bergi  what if i need through coding to abort , should I rebuild the system for single code   ???

Comment: @MohammadAbdullah Sorry, I don't unserstand what you mean by "single code". But it really sounds like you just want to throw an exception (reject the promises).

Comment: I mean if i need to exit the code for some reason , should I rebuild my system analysis !!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the intention correctly, there is no need here to cancel or throw.

You should be able to achieve your ends by rearrangement :

```
findEmployeeByCW('11111', "18-09-2016")
.then(function() {
    return findEmployeeByCWE('111111', "18-09-2016", '111111')
    .then(function(log) {
        return updateLoginTimeTo(log, '08-8668', '230993334');
    }, function(e) {
        return createNewEmployeeLog('224314', "18-09-2016", '230993334', '08-99');
    });
}, function(e) {
    return createEmployeeLoginBy('111111', "18-09-2016", '111111');
})
.then(SaveEmployeeLogToDb)
.then(DisplayLog)
.catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

That should work with the proviso that a `log` object is always delivered to `SaveEmployeeLogToDb` via all possible paths to that point, as implied by the original code.

Comment: Mr @Roamer-1888  you mean that I should build my system well so that I wan't need the cancellation !!??   maybe it 's a solution but what if i need through coding to abort , should I rebuild the system for single code ??

Comment: thanks a lot for your advice Mr @Roamer-1888 , it works for me , I think the main Idea for a Promise is to build the system well , and if an error occurred  it should be bubbled to be handled at the tail  of the  chaining

Answer (score 0):

You can't currently "cancel" promises. But you can use an exception for that purpose:

```
findEmployeeByCW('11111', "18-09-2016").
then(function () {
return findEmployeeByCWE('111111', "18-09-2016", '111111')
}, function () {
console.log('createEmployeeLoginBy')

//*** "return" added
return createEmployeeLoginBy('111111', "18-09-2016", '111111').
then(function (log) {
SaveEmployeeLogToDb(log)

//****
throw new Error('promise_exit');
//****

})
})
.then(function (log) {
return updateLoginTimeTo(log, '08-8668', '230993334')
}, function () {
return createNewEmployeeLog('224314', "18-09-2016",
'230993334', '08-99')
})
.then(SaveEmployeeLogToDb).then(DisplayLog).catch(function (e) {

//****
//Only log if it's not an intended exit
if(e.message != 'promise_exit'){
    console.log(e);
}
//****

})
```

Comment: I tried before , It didn't work , it continued of execution  , I also tried to throw an exception in  SaveEmployeeLogToDb method , but it also failed !!

Comment: Try the updated answer. Returning the createEmployeeLoginBy should work.