# Use cancel() inside a then-chain created by promisifyAll

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

Not sure if I'm clear enough with this title, but assume that I have a class called Foo with `method1`, `method2` and `method3`. I promisify its methods with `promisifyAll`.

Then I have a then-chain and I want to cancel the operation in the middle of the second or first then, and no further then should be called.

I read about Cancellation (http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/cancellation.html) but I don't know how to implement it with promisifyAll.

The code I got plus what I need:

```
var bluebird = require('bluebird');

function Foo() { }

Foo.prototype.method1 = function (cb) {};

Foo.prototype.method2 = function (cb) {};

Foo.prototype.method3 = function (cb) {};

var foo = bluebird.promisifyAll(new Foo());

foo.method1Async()
.then(function (r1) {
  // cancel then-chain
  res.json("Task stopped");
  // just stop right here
  promises.cancel();
})
.then(function (r2) {
  console.log(r2);
}).then(function (r3) {
  console.log(r3);
})
.catch(function (er) {
  console.log('Catch!');
});
```

What is the proper way of having this result?
I know I can just throw something and catch it in the `catch` method, but this would make a very big change in my real code.

Comment: If you know that you want to cancel them, why do you put them there in the first place? Is the cancellation conditional? Is it really done from within the `then` callback? Then you should just throw an exception; cancellation is for external signaling.

Comment: "*I know I can just throw something and catch it in the catch method, but this would make a very big change in my real code.*" - why? It's the right thing to do. What is your real code, and what's the problem with throwing in there?

Comment: @Bergi You're right, in this case the `then` callback should either throw an exception or return e rejected promise which has the same effect. I tried to explain it in detail in [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40515775/use-cancel-inside-a-then-chain-created-by-promisifyall/40515981#40515981) but the OP didn't answer if it worked for him. Please comment if my answer needs any improvement or clarification. Thanks.

Comment: the cancellation is conditional. I didn't want to throw/catch because I was using throw/catch just to deal with exceptions, and not alternative flows.

Comment: If you want to use flow control, [do it with an `if` statement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29500221/1048572). But Bluebird's tested exceptions make throwing a simple alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var bluebird = require('bluebird');

function Foo() { }

Foo.prototype.method1 = function (cb) { cb(null, 'method1'); };
Foo.prototype.method2 = function (cb) { cb(null, 'method2'); };
Foo.prototype.method3 = function (cb) { cb(null, 'method3'); };

var foo = bluebird.promisifyAll(new Foo());

foo.method1Async()
.then(function (r1) {
  console.log('step 1');
  // cancel then-chain
  console.log("Task stopped");
  // just stop right here
  return bluebird.reject('some reason');
})
.then(function (r2) {
  console.log('step 2');
  console.log(r2);
}).then(function (r3) {
  console.log('step 3');
  console.log(r3);
})
.catch(function (er) {
  console.log('Catch!');
  console.log('Error:', er);
});
```

Instead of:

```
  return bluebird.reject('some reason');
```

you can use:

```
  throw 'some reason';
```

and the result would be the same but you didn't want to throw errors so you can return a rejected promise instead.

### Update 1

But if your intention is to run all 3 methods in series then you will also need to return the next promise at each step with something like this:

```
var bluebird = require('bluebird');

function Foo() { }

Foo.prototype.method1 = function (cb) { cb(null, 'method1'); };
Foo.prototype.method2 = function (cb) { cb(null, 'method2'); };
Foo.prototype.method3 = function (cb) { cb(null, 'method3'); };

var foo = bluebird.promisifyAll(new Foo());

foo.method1Async()
.then(function (r1) {
  console.log('step 1');
  console.log('got value:', r1);
  // cancel? change to true:
  var cancel = false;
  if (cancel) {
    console.log("Task stopped");
    return bluebird.reject('some reason');
  } else {
    console.log('Keep going');
    return foo.method2Async();
  }
})
.then(function (r2) {
  console.log('step 2');
  console.log('got value:', r2);
  return foo.method3Async();
}).then(function (r3) {
  console.log('step 3');
  console.log('got value:', r3);
})
.catch(function (er) {
  console.log('Catch!');
  console.log('Error:', er);
});
```

Currently the code in your question would never run any other method than the first one.

### Update 2

Another example that doesn't call the last `catch` for that case:

```
foo.method1Async()
.then(function (r1) {
  console.log('step 1');
  console.log('got value:', r1);
  // cancel? change to true:
  var cancel = true;
  if (cancel) {
    console.log("Task stopped");
    return bluebird.reject('some reason');
  } else {
    console.log('Keep going');
    return foo.method2Async();
  }
})
.then(function (r2) {
  console.log('step 2');
  console.log('got value:', r2);
  return foo.method3Async();
}).then(function (r3) {
  console.log('step 3');
  console.log('got value:', r3);
})
.catch(function (er) {
  if (er === 'some reason') {
    return bluebird.resolve('ok');
  } else {
    return bluebird.reject(er);
  }
})
.catch(function (er) {
  console.log('Catch!');
  console.log('Error:', er);
});
```

### Explanation

Think of it this way: in synchronous code if you had:

```
r1 = fun1();
r2 = fun2();
r3 = fun3();
```

then the only way for fun1 to cancel the execution of fun2 and fun3 would be to throw an exception. And similarly for promises, the only way that one `then` handler could cancel the execution of the next `then` handler is to return a rejected promise. And just like with synchronous code that thrown exception would be caught by the `catch` block, here that rejected promise would be passed to the `catch` handler.

With synchronous code you can have an internal `try/catch` that catches the exception and rethrows it if it isn't the specific one that you used to cancel your execution. With promises you can have an earlier `catch` handler that does essentially the same.

This is what happens with the code in Update 2. The rejection reason is compared to some value (which is `'some reason'` in that example) and if it is equal then a resolved promise is returned and so the next `catch` handler is not called. If it is not equal then the rejection reason is returned again as a rejected promise witch is then passed to the next `catch` handler as a "real" error that you want that last `catch` handler to handle.

Comment: But `reject()` will be caught by the 'catch' statement, right? isn't there a way to make it stop, but not necessarily get caught? my `catch's` already have a logic and they are dealing with real errors. in some cases I want to cancel, but not mix things up

Comment: @VictorFerreira Yes but you can add another `catch` that stops that `catch` from running. See Update 2 in my answer. At every `then` step you can only return another promise - that can either get resolved or rejected. So if you don't want the next `then` to run then you have no other option than return a rejected promise or throw an error. Either way it will call the next `catch` but that `catch` can see what was the value that it got and either return a resolved promise or rejected promise. It's like rethrowing the exception for certain kinds of exceptions but not others in synchronous code.

Comment: @VictorFerreira See the Explanation part in my answer that I added. I hope it clarifies the issue.

Comment: I liked your idea of returning a rejected promise for the next catch. so I created a class called `PromiseHandler` and a method `cancel()`. I throw it and check in the middleware-catch. if it was not a PromiseHandler canceled, I return a rejected promise that will be caught by the next `catch`